# IBM Worklight JSONStore | Remove Document from Collection and erase it from memory

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I have been trying to erase all document from collection and memory before adding new one. I tried it by following methods

1.

```
        WL.JSONStore.get("users").findAll().then(function (arrayResults){
            var options={push:true};
        if(arrayResults.length>0){
            for(var i=1;i<=arrayResults.length;i++){
            WL.JSONStore.get("users").remove(i,options);
            }
        }
            });
```

2.

```
            WL.JSONStore.get("users").findAll().then(function (arrayResults){
            var options={};
        if(arrayResults.length>0){
            for(var i=1;i<=arrayResults.length;i++){
            WL.JSONStore.get("users").erase(i,options);
            }
        }
            });
```

But didn't get success. Its showing all documents by doing `findAll`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [removeCollection](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/JSONStoreInstance.html#removeCollection) API call to remove all docs in a collection, you will have to re-init the collection if you want to use it again.

Alternatively, try following this example:

```
function wlCommonInit () {

  WL.JSONStore.init({
    users: {
      name: 'string'
    }
  })

  .then(function () {
    return WL.JSONStore.get('users').add([{name: 'hello'}, {name: 'world'}]);
  })

  .then(function () {
    return WL.JSONStore.get('users').findAll();
  })

  .then(function (res){

    alert('Before - Docs inside:' + JSON.stringify(res));

    var ids = res.map(function(current){ return current._id  })

    var promises = [];

    while (ids.length) {
      promises.push(WL.JSONStore.get('users').remove(ids.pop()));
    }

    return WLJQ.when.apply(null, promises);
  })

  .then(function () {
    return WL.JSONStore.get('users').findAll();
  })

  .then(function (res) {
    alert('After - Docs inside:' + JSON.stringify(res));
  })

  .fail(function (err) {
    alert('Failed:' + err.toString());
  });
}
```

Comment: Hey! thanks Cnandreu... i solved my problem by using removeCollection API.