# IBM worklight JSON store remove array of documents

Tags: javascript, json, ibm-mobilefirst

I am working in IBM worklight hybrid app,i am using JSON store to store data,to remove records from collection,i am using id and i could able delete single record using id,how to delete multiple records together from JSON store,if any example is there it will be useful,can anyone help me in doing this?Thanks in advance.

Delete function:

```
var id = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jsonindex'));
var query = {
    _id: id
};
var options = {
    push: true
};
try {
    WL.JSONStore.get(PEOPLE_COLLECTION_NAME).remove(query, options)
        .then(function (res) {
        console.log("REMOVE_MSG");
    })
        .fail(function (errorObject) {
        console.log("Not Removed");
    });
} catch (e) {
    alert(INIT_FIRST_MSG);
}
```

JSON data

```
[{
    "_id": 16,
    "json": {
        "name": " Debit",
        "cardmonth": " 8",
        "cardyear": " 2028",
        "number": " 4216170916239547"
    }
}, {
    "_id": 17,
    "json": {
        "name": " Credit",
        "cardmonth": " 7",
        "cardyear": " 2027",
        "number": " 4216170916239547"
    }
}]
```

Comment: How your json format look like. what you need a function or procedure

Comment: jsondata[{"_id":16,"json":{"name":"  Debit","cardmonth":"  8","cardyear":"  2028","number":"  4216170916239547"}},{"_id":17,"json":{"name":" Credit","cardmonth":"   7","cardyear":"   2027","number":"   4216170916239547"}}],i need function..

Comment: How you are deleteing single record

Comment: using id,i could able delete single record,but if i could not able to delete three records continuosly,

Comment: just repeat the loop to delete the 3 records

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
WL.JSONStore.get('collectionName').remove([...], options);
```

Replace `...` with `{_id: 1}, {_id: 2}` or whatever query you want to use to remove documents.

If it doesn't work, please upgrade to the latest version of Worklight and try again.

Relevant:

- [PI10959: JSONSTORE FAILS TO REMOVE ALL DOCS IN THE DOC ARRAY WHEN A DOC ARRAY IS PASSED](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI10959)
- [IBM Worklight JSONStore | Remove Document from Collection and erase it from memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21188557/186909)

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to  delete the single record. its easy to delete multiple record. but it raises some performance issues you have so many records.

`var id="3";` If you are deleting this one by using `Delete method`. just do it for multiple records

```
var ids=[];
when user selects item ids.push(item.id);

for(i=0;i<ids.length;i++){
Delete(ids[i]); //its your Delete method
}
```