# Worklight - Remove several documents in the JSONStore database

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I am developping a mobile application using Worklight and I want to remove several documents in the JSONStore database using a query.

I tried to do the following :

`WL.JSONStore.get('collection').remove([{MYID: "1111"}, {MYID: "2222"}],{push: false})
        .then(function(){
            //Handle success
        })
        .fail(function(errorObject){
            //Handle failure
        });`

Unfortunatelly, I got the error :

> BAD_PARAMETER_EXPECTED_DOCUMENT_OR_ARRAY_OF_DOCUMENTS

It's weird because in the Worklight JSONStore remove function documentation, it's written :
`@param doc {Document or Array of Documents or Query or _id}`.

Or maybe do I have to retrieve the documents and then remove them ?
I think about doing a loop over the documents too, but I would prefer to use a "cleaner" solution because I want to know when all the documents have been successfully removed.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

That is a known bug, it has been fixed in the latest version.

Take a look at the following relevant links:

- [PI10959: JSONSTORE FAILS TO REMOVE ALL DOCS IN THE DOC ARRAY WHEN A DOC ARRAY IS PASSED](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI10959)
- [IBM Worklight JSONStore | Remove Document from Collection and erase it from memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21188557/186909)

Comment: OK, so I have just upgraded my Worklight version from 6.1.0.01 to 6.2 and I can't deploy the application on the WL server anymore ... I have the following error : `FWLSE0009W: User identity is null. Check your application's authentication requirements`. I think I will open an other post for this ...

Comment: That error is unrelated to JSONStore. You should absolutely create another post for that.