# Worklight 6.1 JSONStore remove issue in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I meet a remove documents issue in iPhone using WL.JSONStore.

My code is like following:

```
var jstores = new Array();
for(var i=0 ; i<args.length; i++) {
    var _id = _IDMap[args[i].id];
    var document = {
        _id : _id,
        json: args[i]
    };
    console.log("prepare to remove id: "+_id);
    jstores.push(document);
}
WL.JSONStore.get("dataSet").remove(jstores,{push:true}).then(function(result) {
    console.error("remove num: "+result);
    return true;
}).fail(function (error){
    return false;
});
```

I want to using WL.JSONStore.remove function to remove some documents. This works fine in Android but.. in iPhone, only one document will be removed whatever the number of documents I want to remove.
And the result of the callback function is always equals 1...

I don't know why. Is anyone who has meet the same problem like me? My iOS version is 6.1, iPhone5

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following:

- [PI10959: JSONSTORE FAILS TO REMOVE ALL DOCS IN THE DOC ARRAY WHEN A DOC ARRAY IS PASSED](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI10959) - *The fix for this APAR is currently targeted for fixpack 6.1.0.1.*
- [IBM Worklight JSONStore | Remove Document from Collection and erase it from memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21188557/186909)

Comment: Well. Thank you for your solution. I've tried that and it works fine in devices now. But... in desktop browser(Chrome), in this way can only delete one item... All thing is reverse...

Comment: Your code should work fine after you update to the latest fix pack, if not [open a PMR](http://ibm.co/1B9KHGz). If you're calling `replace(...)` multiple times [remember this line from the docs](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_jsonstore_troubleshooting_overview.html): *The JavaScript implementation of JSONStore expects code to be called serially. Wait for an operation to finish before you call the next one.* That's probably why it's working in the production environments (e.g. Android, iOS) and not the JS Implementation (e.g.Chrome)